# Modifying libcomposite module doesn't work

Tags: kernel, driver, modules, gadget

I'm trying to modify the libcomposite module in a way that it prints the functions of which are loaded to the log file.

I'm using an Raspberry Pi Zero W with the 4.9.20+ Kernel. I updated everything with the rpi-source then edited the `composite.c` file in `drivers/usb/gadget` folder to print with `printk(..)`.

And recompiled everything with `make modules SUBDIR=drivers/usb/gadget` and the installed everything with `make modules_install SUBDIR=drivers/usb/gadget`.

The libcomposite is loaded with `modprobe libcomposite` in a `systemd service` and then the functions are appended.

But the problem is that the messages of `printk(..)` are neither shown in `dmesg` nor any log files.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

This works for me, but there are many pitfalls that you could have stumbled on.

- Correct install path: I cross-compiled from a PC so had to make sure `INSTALL_MOD_PATH` was specified properly. It sounds like you're building on the Pi itself so that this may not be an issue, but to double-check, confirm that the timestamp on `/lib/modules/4.9.56+/kernel/drivers/usb/gadget/libcomposite.ko` (or newer kernel version) has been updated.
- Correct kernel.img: Make sure `kernel.img` is updated as well. If you run the old kernel it'll pull `libcomposite.ko` out of `/lib/modules/4.9.35+/` (or whatever your original kernel version is). You could nuke the old modules directory to be certain.
- kernel message level: `KERN_INFO` (6) is too high for messages to land in dmesg by default. Try `printk(KERN_WARNING ...)` for level 4 initially. `pr_info()` may be preferable for modules and does not have this complication.
- Which part of composite.c are you putting your printout in? If `usb_add_function()`, note that this won't be called until you've fully configured a gadget and do the `ls /sys/class/udc > UDC` step.

By the way, I find the `SUBDIR` variable having no effect, but it doesn't hurt.